# How can I limit the BB DateTimePicker?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, datetimepicker

I use a DateTimePicker in my app and I want it to allow to select only past dates, I use it to allow the user to select his date of birth and I would like it to start and end at a given year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a quick look at the [DateTimePicker documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/DateTimePicker.html) shows that you use the `setDateTime`, `setMaximumDate` and `setMinimumDate` methods to set the timespans and initial date.

Comment: Yes but the problem it's how you set the date, you have to pass a Calendar object to it but making the object with the specific date can't be done how I see it done online. They say to use SimpleDateFormat and use it to parse a String with the date you want, for example "01-Jan-1920" but apparently the BB API doesn't have the parse method for SimpleDateFormat, and the J2ME package that has simple date format apparently does not exist in the Java version that the BB plugin uses. It should be java.text.SimpleDateFormat but it's not there

Comment: You get a Calendar instance using Calendar.getInstance() and then set its fields to the correct values. See the API docs for Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this the following way:

```
Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
minDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
minDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1920);

_datePicker.setMinimumDate(minDate);
```